# what is the mysql error in following?

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

This is to create a new table with name as users id

```
$tablename=$_SESSION['lgn-id'];

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $tablename(
qtno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(qtno),
 qt VARCHAR())")
 or die(mysql_error());  

echo " so I created one!";
```

It's showing the following error table name being text36.txt@gmail.com

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com( qtno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(qtno), qt V' at line 1

Comment: Your table name is `@gmail.com`?

Comment: no its text36.txt@gmail.com @sachleen

Comment: You cannot use '@' in the table name without backticks.

Comment: On another note as of `PHP 5.5.0` `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: ok but still its showing error for text.36txtgmail.com too why is that? @rs.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @Mr_J use escape characters like mentioned in answers below, but why do you want to create separate table for each user

Comment: an not only that if the table name is txt also then also it gives an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 4`

Comment: @Mr_J you didn't specify length for varchar field and you create DDL syntax is wrong

Comment: @rs. sir if i use sql injection and all then can i create a table with email-id as table name... and i want to do so bcoz i want to store diff users posts in different tables.. i have a main table too which stores users basic info wont

Comment: @Mr_J, that is bad idea, lets say you have 1000+ users, do you want to create 1000+ tables? create table for post like `UserId, Post` and store userid from user table and post

Comment: @rs. but why is it bad to create thounds of table? is there any limitations on that? sorry i am jst stater

Comment: It's not a matter of limitations (although having thousands or millions of tables in a DBMS would cause problems per se). It's a matter of good design.

Comment: @ypercube so sir how cud i manage posts of different users because it wud have different no. of posts for each user? and how wud i manage rows then?.. lets say how do facebook do that?.. sorry if i am sounding like an idiot but i have no exprnc

Comment: @ypercube SIR Please can u enlightten me on this please sir..

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Mr_J , also, get the [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create statement should be

```
CREATE TABLE `$tablename`(
qtno INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
qt VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY(qtno))
```

And Creating separate table for each user is bad idea, lets say you have 1000+ users, do you want to create 1000+ tables? create table for post like `UserId, Post` and store userid from user table and post

You can create Posts table like

```
CREATE TABLE UserPosts
(
   id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   UserId Varchar(100),
   UserPost varchar(1024),
   InserDate DateTime,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Then you can do

```
select UserId, UserPost FROM UserPosts Where UserId = 'text36.txt@gmail.com'
```

Comment: sir using `text36.txt@gmail.com` did wrked

Comment: so sir how cud i manage posts of different users because it wud have different no. of posts for each user? and how wud i manage rows then?.. lets say how do facebook do that?.. sorry if i am sounding like an idiot but i have no exprnc @rs.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the unquoted table name as well as `VARCHAR()`. It has to have a length e.g. `VARCHAR(100)`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pretty obvious from the error, you can't have an `@` character in your table name.

You can wrap it in backticks to fix that. You also need to specify a length for `varchar()`

Refrences: [9.2. Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html), [11.1.6.1. The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//char.html)